# Up-to-date documentation on how to create metadata for fungible token program?

Tags: solana-program, token, metadata, mainnet

We are trying to deploy our token (AIDS) on mainnet: https://explorer.solana.com/address/ExCgGC6CEegjjif7yqxpcreEaarb83K8YaXzmf3PRWAZ . When we are trying to create metadata for this token, we cannot find up-to-date methods and documentation, in general. Can someone point us to up-to-date documentation and examples on how to create metadata for a fungible token on mainnet?

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

[Solana Metadata Pointer](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/metadata-pointer) - newer, with less fees, but less widely supported.

[Metaplex token metadata docs](https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata) - older and more expensive, but more popular.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a tool to create tokens (or add metadata to an existing token), if you want to use it :)

https://token-metadata.effe2.xyz/

Feel free to contact me on my twitter account if you have any problem using it